# How do I overlay multiple sns distplots or change the colour based on a secondary variable using a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a pandas dataframe with a 'frequency_mhz' variable and a 'type' variable. I want to create a dist plot using seaborne that overlays all of the frequencys but changes the colour based on the 'type'.

```
small_df = df[df.small_airport.isin(['Y'])]
medium_df = df[df.medium_airport.isin(['Y'])]
large_df = df[df.large_airport.isin(['Y'])]

plt.figure() 
sns.distplot(small_df['frequency_mhz'], color='red')

plt.figure() 
sns.distplot(medium_df['frequency_mhz'], color='green')

plt.figure() 
sns.distplot(large_df['frequency_mhz'])
```

[image: seaborne dist plots]

Is there a way I can overlay the 3 into one plot? or a way ive missed to change the colour of the bars based on another variable as you can with 'hue=' in other plots?

Comment: The seaborn way would be to concatenate the 3 dataframes, adding a new identifying column, and then use hue.  Note that `sns.distplot` is an old function, its new version, for this case, is [`sns.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) with parameters to tell whether you want shared bins (`common_bins=True`), show the proportions of each subset (`common_norm=True`) and the way of combining the plots (`multiple=...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `ax` as kwarg to superimpose your plots:

```
small_df = df[df.small_airport.isin(['Y'])]
medium_df = df[df.medium_airport.isin(['Y'])]
large_df = df[df.large_airport.isin(['Y'])]

ax = sns.distplot(small_df['frequency_mhz'], color='red')
sns.distplot(medium_df['frequency_mhz'], color='green', ax=ax)
sns.distplot(large_df['frequency_mhz'], ax=ax)
plt.show()
```